# Comparing two lists (as sets)

Tags: list, scheme, equals

I'm trying to check whether two lists have the same elements (i.e., that they are equal, when treated as sets).  E.g.,

```
(set-eq? '(1 2 3 4) '(2 3 4))
;=> #f
```

It's not working with numbers like that:

```
(set-eq? (1 2 3 4) '(4 3 2 1))
;=> #f, but I need #t
```

Here is my code:

```
(define (set-eq? xs ys)
  (cond ((and (null? xs) (null? ys)) #t)
        ((or (null? xs) (null? ys))  #f) 
        ((equal? (car xs) (car ys)) (set-eq? (cdr xs) (cdr ys))) 
        (else #f)))
```

What's wrong with this code?

Comment: BTW two lists are equal if all their parts are equal. i.e. `(equal? '(a b c) '(a b c)) ==> #t` while `(equal? '(a b c) '(b c a)) ==> #f`. Your code works similar to `equal?`

Comment: Write a `subset?` procedure that tests if a list is a subset of another list (that is: if all the elements in one list are contained in the other list), and then test whether `(and (subset? l1 l2) (subset? l2 l1))` is true, if that happens, then they're equal according to the set definition of equality.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I suggested in the comments, the trick is using the [`member`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/pairs.html#%28def._%28%28lib._racket%2Fprivate%2Flist..rkt%29._member%29%29) procedure to test membership of an element in a list:

```
(define (subset? l1 l2)
  (or (null? l1)
      (and (member  (car l1) l2)
           (subset? (cdr l1) l2))))

(define (set-equal? l1 l2)
  (and (subset? l1 l2)
       (subset? l2 l1)))
```

Now it'll work as a procedure for equality-testing between lists seen as sets:

```
(set-equal? '(1 2 3 4) '(4 3 2 1))
=> #t
```